# Discrete predictors in a mixed effects model in JAGS

Tags: jags, hierarchical-bayesian

I'm fitting a random effects hierarchical model in JAGS and have a question regarding discrete predictors in the contexts of mixed effects models. In my data there is a group variable, which is the random effect. Within each group, a collection of subjects is further divided into control + experimental units determined by dosage level. Let's say there's 8 dosage levels and 10 groups. I want to build a model that looks at the dose-response overall and by the group random effects.

In essence, for a single group, my model will estimate 1 coefficient for the random group effects and 7 coefficients for group-varying effects of dosage level.

In my JAGS model, do I have to create create an indicator variable for each of the experimental dosage levels or can I work with the original variable (i.e. all control+8 dosage levels)? How can I incorporate the reference category in my coding?

A similar example would also be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want effects for `groups` and for `dosage` varying on groups? It would be something like this (simplified):

```
beta0 ~ dsomething()
sigma ~ dsomething()

for (k in 1:K) {
   beta1[k] ~ dsomething()
   for (l in 1:L) {
      beta2[k, l] ~ dsomething()
      eta[k, l] <- beta0 + beta1[k] + beta2[k, l]
   }
}

for (i in 1:N) {
   y[i] ~ dnorm(eta[group[i], dosage[i]], sigma)
}
```

where `dsomething` is some distribution of your choice while `group` and `dosage` are indicator variables.

Btw, you can check a book on hierarchical regression by [Gelman and Hill (2007)](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/) for more examples. ["The BUGS Book"](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781584888499) is also a nice introduction on this. However, I personally would recommend you [Stan](http://mc-stan.org/) for this kind of models - it also has a nice documentation and [online support](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/stan-users).

Comment: Just want to clarify - have you parametrized eta in such a way so that beta0 captures the information from the control dosage level in addition to the reference group?

Comment: `beta0` is an intercept, `beta1` is estimated for each of the `groups` separately.

Comment: Isn't eta overparametrized now because beta1[k] has has all  K groups, so that beta0 is redundant?

Comment: If your response variable is centered (i.e. it has mean = 0), you can drop `beta0`, however, if it is not then `beta0` will make things easier for a sampler.